# mapstruct apply method to all objects from a list

Tags: java, mapstruct

My problem: I want to map a class of type `PersonB` to `PersonA` using `mapstruct` and to trim all the strings that are find in the `List<Address> addresses` .

```
public class PersonA {

     List<Address> addresses;
}

public class PersonB {
     List<Address> addresses;
}

public Address {
     String name;
}

@Mapper
public interface PersonMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "addresses.name", qualifiedByName = "trim")
    public PersonA mapToPersonA(final PersonB person);

    @Named("trim")
    public static String trim(final String value) {
        return value != null ? value.trim() : null;
    }
}
```

My structure is a little bit more complicated, but I've tried to summarize it. I don't know why this mapper is not working as expected and why the strings are not trimmed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently MapStruct does not allow a way to define nested target mappings for Collections.

In addition to that both of your `PersonA` and `PersonB` have the same type for the `Address`. This means that MapStruct will not create a copy of your object, but it will rather copy it by reference.

To solve the first problem you'll need to define an explicit method for mapping an `Address`

e.g.

```
@Mapper
public interface PersonMapper {

    PersonA mapToPersonA(final PersonB person);

    @Mapping(target = "name", qualifiedByName = "trim")
    Address cloneAddress(Address address);

    @Named("trim")
    public static String trim(final String value) {
        return value != null ? value.trim() : null;
    }
}
```

This will also fix the second problem since there is a specific method that MapStruct will use to map an Address.